# How to pull from a new branch in TFS by copying local contents from another branch

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

There are two branches in the TFS repo. Branch 1 and Branch 2 . Branch 2 was created recently and I want to pull contents of branch 2. I have pulled branch 1 in my machine. As there is limited bandwidth, I was wondering is there any way to copy the contents from branch 1 folder into branch 2 folder in my local machine so that I won't have to utilize much of my mobile data. I tried it but source control explorer in visual studio is not detecting the files I copied to branch 2 folder from branch 1.

Is there any tricks to make it work?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Do you use TFVC or Git version control?

Comment: It is TFVC. Sorry can't migrate to Git now.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT thanks for the suggestion. But like I said, the copied files are not detected even in excluded changes. Mapping is correct

Comment: Do you select the correct workspace? Please try to create a new workspace and map the Branch2 to a local path, then test again.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT Tried that as well. Didn't work. I guess you are saying these suggestions based on git experience. Yes. This technique works in git environment. I am trying to do the same in TFVC

Comment: How's your issue going? If the issue persists, could you please capture some screenshots how you map workspace and copy files?

Answer (score -1):

**Update:**

> Since you use TFVC, you need to make sure the folder you try to copy
>   to has been mapped to Branch 2. And you should be able to see the copy
>   files detected in Excluded Changes after you copy the files in the
>   mapped folder.
>
> When you connect to TFS again, you need to perform “Get Latest” for
>   the Branch 2. If you modify files in the mapped folder, you would get
>   conflicts when you perform "get latest", choose keep local version,
>   and then the modified files will show in Included Changes, you just
>   need to check them in.

---

TFS provide two models of version control: Git and Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC).

Git is a distributed version control system. Each developer has a copy of the source repository on their dev machine. Developers can commit each set of changes on their dev machine and perform version control operations such as history and compare without a network connection. Branches are lightweight. When you need to switch contexts, you can create a private local branch.

Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC) is a centralized version control system. Typically, team members have only one version of each file on their dev machines. Historical data is maintained only on the server. Branches are path-based and created on the server.

If you use Git version control, you can create a private local branch and push the commits later. If you use TFVC version control, you would see the copy files detected in Excluded Changes after you copy the files in the local path of the branch. You can promote the changes as new files, which will cause conflicts when you check in.

For your scenario, Git version control will be more suitable for you. If you use TFVC, you can migrate them to Git repos:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-from-tfvc?view=azure-devops

[image]

Comment: This doesn't attempt to answer the question. Telling them "you should migrate to a completely different version control system" does nothing to solve the stated problem.